# how to remove the mapping resource property from hibernate.cfg file

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i am currently working on one project. In my project there are many entity/POJO files. currently i am using simple hibernate.cfg.xml to add all the mapping files in to the configuration like :-

```
<mapping resource="xml/ClassRoom.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="xml/Teacher.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="xml/Student.hbm.xml"/>
```

i am having huge number of mapping files, which makes my hibernate.cfg file looks a bit messy, so is there any way so that i do not need to add the above in to the hibernate.cfg file. rather there can be any other way to achieve the same.. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Configuration` programmatically and use [`Configuration#addClass(Class)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addClass(java.lang.Class)) to specify the mapped class (and Hibernate will load the mapping file for you). From the javadoc:

> Read a mapping as an application resource using the convention that a class
>   named `foo.bar.Foo` is mapped by a file `foo/bar/Foo.hbm.xml`
>   which can be resolved as a classpath resource.

So you could do something like this:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
    .addClass(org.hibernate.auction.Item.class)
    .addClass(org.hibernate.auction.Bid.class)
    ...
    .configure();
SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

#### See also

- [Section 3.1. Programmatic configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic)

Comment: which only transfers the "problem" to another place. I think he wants hibernate to magically understand what he wants ;)

Comment: @Bozho True. But the OP asked *is there any way so that I do not need to add the above in to the hibernate.cfg.xml file* and my suggestion strictly answers this question when using mapping files :)

Comment: Indeed. And mine is also a good alternative, but let's see what he will prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [use annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping).

```
@Entity
public class Teacher {

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String address;

    etc..
}
```

Hibernate will automatically detect classes that are annotated with `@Entity`.

Comment: Hi Bozho.. this is fine and will work exactly fine.. but for this i need to change the class files.. which is again a messy work.. can u plz tell me how to achieve the same without changing a lot in my project..

Comment: there isn't a way. You have to specify this information _somewhere_.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Configuration class itself does not provide a magic addAllEntities method. But you can use [AnnotationSessionFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html) [setPackagesToScan](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan(java.lang.String[])) method. Keep in mind it just works when using annotated Entity class and it is a Spring dependent class

```
AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();

sessionFactory.setDataSource(<javax.sql.DataSource> implementation goes here)
sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String [] {"xml"});
```

Answer (score 0):

the addDirectory()/addJar() method of Configuration uses all .hbm.xml files found inside a specified directory/JAR-File. you will need to hardcode that location, but only that one